# Distributing $4$ distinct balls to $3$ distinct baskets, expected value of the maximum number of balls in one basket?

Tags: probability

> We have $4$ distinct balls that we want to distribute to $3$ distinct baskets. Let $F$ be a random variable where $f(\omega) = \text{the maximum number of balls in any basket}$. What is the expected value of $F$?

So I said:

> I will use $E(F) = \sum_{a \in \mathbb R} {a \cdot Pr(F=a) } = 4 \cdot Pr(F=4) + 3 \cdot Pr(F=3) + 2 \cdot Pr(F=2)$.

But then, what is $Pr(F=a)$ when given that the balls are distinct, and so are the baskets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  You must have at least two balls in some bucket and can't have more than four.  The easiest way is just to count.  There are $3^4=81$ total possibilities.  $4$ of them have all the balls in one bucket.  How many with $3$ balls in one bucket and one in another?  All the rest have a maximum of $2$, so subtract from $81$.

Comment: Why $4$ of them in one bucket? I mean, we can put them in one of the three (which is $3$ possibilities) but dont we have to multiply by the inner ordering of the balls ($4!$) and the ordering of the buckets ($3!$) since they are all distinct?

Comment: To get the maximum number of balls in a bucket to be $4$, they all have to go in the same bucket.  You can choose the bucket for the first ball in $4$ ways, but then the others are fixed.  We don't care about ordering of the balls or buckets, just the labels.

Comment: Oh alright. What do you mean by "labels" though?

Comment: The buckets are labeled A,B,C and the balls 1,2,3,4.  The labels tell us that having all the balls in A is different from all the balls in B or all the balls in C.  It also says having 12 in A and 34 in B is different from 14 in A and 23 in B.  The chances would change without the labels.  Without labels, there is only one way to have all the balls in the same bucket and only one way to have two balls in each of two buckets, so the chance of each of these would be the same.  With labels, the chance of two plus two is much higher.  It agrees with the idea of throwing the balls into buckets.